# How to change state of one Stateful Widget from another Stateful Widget in Flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

In this code, I want to show indexed widgets by changing the index from the Navigation drawer i.e. The main `MaterialApp` shows widget according to the index(widgetIndex). The index is updated but the widget does not change until I hot reload it. So, I want it to reload the `MyApp` widget from the drawer widget.

**main.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:indexed/page1.dart';
import 'package:indexed/page2.dart';
import 'drawer.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  //set widgetIndex(int widgetIndex) {widgetIndex = DrawerS.widgetIndex;}
  int widgetIndex = SideDrawerState.widgetIndex;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Container(
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: widgetIndex,
          children: <Widget>[
            Page1(), //A Scaffold wid.
            Page2(), //A Scaffold wid.
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**drawer.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SideDrawer extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  SideDrawerState createState() => SideDrawerState();
}

class SideDrawerState extends State<SideDrawer> {

  static int widgetIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            title: Text('1'),
            onTap: () async {
              setState(() => widgetIndex = 0);

              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('2'),
            onTap: (){
              setState(() => widgetIndex = 1);

              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function field in your **SideDrawer** that takes an **index** as a parameter.

Call the function passing the appropriate parameter in the **onTap** of each **ListTile**.

In your **MyApp** create a variable with initial value of 0 then when setting the **SideDrawer** add the **onTap** attribute then change the value of the in the **setState**

Like this

```
class MyApp2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyApp2State createState() => MyApp2State();
}
class MyApp2State extends State<MyApp2> {

  var widgetIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: IndexedStack(
            index: widgetIndex,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("djdhjhd"),
              Text("nonono")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      drawer: SideDrawer(
        onTap: (index){
          setState(() {
            widgetIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SideDrawer extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function(int index) onTap;
  SideDrawer({this.onTap});

  @override
  SideDrawerState createState() => SideDrawerState();
}

class SideDrawerState extends State<SideDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            title: Text('1'),
            onTap: () async {
              widget.onTap(0);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text('2'),
            onTap: (){
              widget.onTap(1);
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The output:

[image]

I hope this helps you.

Comment: There are other ways to it...You can use the provider https://pub.dev/packages/provider for managing state

Comment: this was helpful, but I want to change the full widget. here only the body is changed. Please check this video where I have to press ctrl+s after tapping in the drawer to update the screen. https://drive.google.com/open?id=19rM-k3ie5eoPPJ__9GSnY7tefSagNCtg      please tell me how to change the state automatically.